# Limit of integral of the $n$-th root

Tags: integration, radicals

I need a litle help finding the solution for this exercise:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\int_{0}^{1} (2017+x^n)^n dx}$$
I think I should start from $$ 2017\leq 2017+x^n \leq 2018$$ but from there I end up with $$2017 \leq \sqrt[n]{\int_{0}^{1} (2017+x^n)^n dx} \leq 2018 $$ and I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Should this be tagged [tag:contest-math]?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}$?

Comment: I think it can be calculated by Power Inequality

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{ \int_{0}^{1} (1+x^n)^n dx}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212836/computing-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-int-01-1xnn-dx). (Just replace $1$ with $2017$).

Comment: Yes, thank you very much @Zacky!

Comment: @Zacky Your first suggestion doesn't work, as $f$ isn't a fixed function, but rather a sequence of functions indexed by $n$ (we have $f_n(x)=2017+x^n$).

Comment: Use that$$2017x^n+x^n\le2017+x^n\le 2018$$